# invisible charater appearing in new line of string

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code not being able to capitalize the first letter of any string after the first string and not displaying the last word of the string. the code uses linux redirection to read a series of titles from an input file. The first letter of each word needs to be capitalized and the rest lowercase, and each word needs to be separated by one black space. This is the output of test data:

> ```
> The  5th  
> the  Cat In The 
> one Fish Two Fish  Red Fish Blue
> ```

Notice also how there is two spaces between the and 5th and fish and red

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void reform (string& imup);
int main ()
{
     string word;
     string temp = " ";
     string letters;
     getline(cin,letters);
     int length;
     length = 0; 
     word = "";
     while (cin)
     {  
        length = letters.size();
        for (int i =0; i < length; i++)
        {

            if (letters[i] != ' ' && letters[i] != '\n')
            {
                word = word + letters[i];
            }
            else if ((letters[i] == ' ' && isalpha(letters[i-1])) ||
                     (letters[i] == ' ' && isalpha(letters[i+1]))) 
            {
                reform(word); 
                cout<< word <<" " ;
                word = "";
            }
            else if ((letters[i] == ' ' && isdigit(letters[i-1])) ||
                     (letters[i] == ' ' && isdigit(letters[i+1]))) 
            {
                reform(word); 
                cout<< word <<" " ;
                word = "";
             }

         }
         cout<< endl;
         getline(cin,letters);
     }

     return 0;
}


void reform (string& imup)
{
    int size;
    // cout <<"hi "; 
    size = imup.length();
    imup[0] = toupper(imup[0]);
    for (int i=1; i < size; i++)
         imup[i] = tolower(imup[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post, and properly indent your code. The random indentation makes its logic hard to follow.

Comment: (Unrelated) Use `while(getline(..))` rather than two calls to `getline`.

Comment: You can merge the test for isalpha and isdigit together with || (that way you don't need to repeat the merge.).  This will blow up if the first character of a line is space.  What happens if the character before a space is neither a letter nor a digit (eg $, @, or *)

Comment: nothing should happen

Answer (score 0):

Given `a__b` as input (with the underscore representing a blank), this will recognize word end at the blank after the a, printing `a_`. It will then also detect word end at the blank before the b, printing `_`, because word is empty.

I'm not sure why you look at the character *after* a blank. You should also ensure i is not 0 before checking the former character.

Why not simply output word if it's nonempty either when encountering a blank or the end of the input?

Something like:

```
while (getline(cin, letters)) {
  bool first = true;
  string word;
  for (string::const_iterator s = letters.begin(); s != letters.end(); ++s) {
    if (*s == ' ' || *s == '\r' || *s == '\n') {
      if (!word.empty()) {
        if (!first) cout << ' ';
        reform(word);
        cout << word;
        word = "";
        first = false;
      }
    }
    else
      word += *s;
  }
  if (!word.empty()) {
    if (!first) cout << ' ';
    reform(word);
    cout << word;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

The first flag then avoids printing a trailing blank on a line.

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you mean, can you provide an example? thanks

Comment: 1.  strip the newline (if present).  Then `for (char l : letters) if (c != ' ') word+=l; else if (word.size() > 0) { output word }; if (word.size() != 0 { output word }; cout << endl;`  (The second if is outside the for loop)

Comment: You probably will want to move the "if (!word.empty())" and associated code into a little function.

Comment: Well yes, I'd combine that with the reform function as `maybe_output_word()` or something. I'm just trying to show the principle; final polish is up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of your code (you can replace **for** loops with iterators):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <cctype>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
      string word;
      string temp = " ";
      string letters;
      int i, len;
      while(getline(cin,letters))
      {
           len = letters.size();
           for(i = 0; (i < len) && isspace(letters[i]); i++)
                 ;
           if(i >= len)
               cout << "Empty line is entered" << endl;
           else
           {
               string out_string = letters.substr(i);
               out_string.replace(0, 1, 1, std::toupper(out_string[0]));
               for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
                   out_string.replace(i, 1, 1,    std::tolower(out_string[i]));
               cout << out_string << endl;
           }
      }
  }
```